# Горячие клавиши в pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Есть ли комбинация клавиш в pycharm для переключеня на левую боковую панель, чтобы потом стрелочками можно было переходить по файлам и каталогам?

Comment: В меню есть список всех комбинаций

Answer (score 2):

Случайно наткнулся сам. Если нажать alt + 1, то происходит переход в боковую панель и можно перемещаться с помощью стрелочек. Перейти обратно можно нажав Esc. (это на линуксе)

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, Pycharm и intellij IDEA разрабатывают одни парни(JetBrains) и не исключено, что горячие клавиши одни на всех, попробуй: `COMAND + 1, COMAND + 2 и тд.;` на Windows не знаю как, но скорей всего через ALT или CTRL.